# Lenovo x301 - Can't boot from latest distro on dvd

Tags: boot, dvd

Got an old laptop from a friend but it had win10 on it which isn't really supported and was painfully slow

Downloaded and burnt an iso (with verify) of latest distro but laptop won't boot from it. It tries but console shows odd errors after we get the ubuntu loading screen

So I dug out an old distro (trusty tahir) and booted into that no problem at all and installed it. Sadly my old disc was 32 bit so tried to create a second boot disc this time from ubuntu

But same problem

Anyone come across this? Will find a USB stick and try burning and booting to that.

Leaving it on 32 bit old distro isn't really an option :-)

Rich

Comment: Please be specific with details; what is the *latest distro" as you understand it?  Ubuntu has many products, and many releases (some having different ISO install options, with many architecture choices) & your question is void of specifics.  Please also note Ubuntu hasn't intended *optical* media be used for installs since Ubuntu 22.04 LTS; ie. it should be avoided as it can take >60 minutes as the ISO is no longer written to ensure it's fast there (*being optimized for flash media; esp. with media verification... did you wait long enough?*).

Comment: At the start of the boot attempt if i escape from the logo screen i see: "can't open /dev/sr0" repeated lots. So I'm guessing it's not detecting the hard drive? Fine with an older distro though? Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc. Didn't write down the distro just the one get ubuntu offered me. But will try burning to usb stick

Comment: Of course file name tells me. Ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64

Comment: Also all the big red errors on the console log didn't give me warm fuzzies that it was working ok. But maybe it might have live booted after an hour? Who's got that kinda time? Old distro booted in a couple of minutes

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is the 2022-April release (first re-spin) so it's not the latest (*22.10 or the 2022-October release is later of course*), but key is it's an ISO that was intended for use only from *flash* media & not *optical*. Anything up to and included 20.04 (or the 2020-April) release was faster on *optical* so why not used the media it was designed to be used with?  (ie. USB flash drive).  The warnings may not be an issue; eg. if you're not resuming a hibernated system, an error that the *hibernate file wasn't found* is expected & good! ie. if you don't read what they are; why care?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)