# Upgrading to ubuntu 22.04 LTS problem

Tags: lts, boot-repair

I have upgraded my linux version 21~ without LTS to 22.04 LTS.
I have used apk upgrade etc., upgrading, updating commands and restart laptop.

I have edit my

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

to proper one and upgrading worked..

I have error

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon
```

I can't run my linux and it doesn't go even to the login step.

Answer (score 0):

Because you upgraded from a currently unsupported release to Ubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 does not boot to the desktop environment, it looks to me like you are looking at a situation in which you have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: So basically I could install one more time but this time directly from this ISO. https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ and it should work perfectly fine :) ? 
or Karel maybe you recommend other version than ubuntu. Thanks in advance. I was thinking about mint cinamon

Comment: I recommend installing Ubuntu from a live USB by following the instructions at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/674454/).

Comment: I donn't have seperate option to Install. I have only Try or Install, after clicking it: "Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set.." and nothing happens It founds jellyfish etc.
Reading packages indexes... Done /n Writing new source list \n Spirce ;;ost emtroes fpr tjos dosc are" deb cdrom Jellyfish / jammy main restricted. and this line with repeat

Comment: Try installing Ubuntu from an Ubuntu live USB instead of from a set of CDs. That's the way everyone else does it. Please post another question if you have another problem that is different from the problem in your original question. That's the way Ask Ubuntu and other Stack Exchange network sites work.

Comment: I got it. Kernel and bios could be a problem but I do not know how to handle it from boot position.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448704/cant-access-to-install-ubuntu-22-04-lts