# Problems With The Ubuntu Installation

Tags: boot, command-line, usb, bios

this is my first time trying to use a linux operating system (ubuntu) but when i start from (uefi)Usb 2.0 that i think is my bootable usb drive i end up in the Efi Shell and it mentions startup.nsh then it just becomes a cmd with a `shell>` thing in it.

Comment: Needs a lot of details added to the question. What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? Did you verify the ISO that you downloaded? Are you following a tutorial? What program did you use to make the bootable Live Media USB? Those are just some of the things that the question needs added. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview Some links for you to look at.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441/) and [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)