# Can I install 12.04 on a Windows 10 computer?

Tags: 12.04, 22.04

I have a disc with 12.04 on it. I tried to download 22.04 on a usb stick but it won't install as it says not enough space even though it is a 32 GB drive. Tried multiple times and keep getting the same error. So, I figured I'd try 12.04, and then upgrade to a newer version. Is this possible?

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 12.04 ESM was in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/03/15/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-reaches-end-of-life-on-april-28-2017/

Comment: FYI:  You can write all current Ubuntu ISOs to a 8GB drive, so your problem with 22.04 was either a bad download; or you used software to write it that couldn't cope with the 22.04 ISO you used (*Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop ISO for example requires updated software due to size; was your software updated & current?*)  You didn't specify which product/architecture?  ie. Server? Desktop? etc. or *amd64* but I've assumed *amd64* & *desktop* as your problem with 22.04 can occur with outdated ISO writing software for example.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** I'd strongly advise against trying to install and then upgrade from such an old version of the Ubuntu OS. You'd be much better off figuring out your issue with creating a functioning USB drive (32 GB is more than enough for an Ubuntu installer).

Comment: Possible does not mean you should.  Put the effort into finding out why your 22.04 download/install media creation/installation failed.  Give us specific error messages so we can provide assistance.

Comment: @guiverc, you beat me to that suggestion by 8 seconds!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441/)