# Dell Latitude E7450 downloading issue for Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: dell

I am brand new, my laptop is not. Windows 10 is working with no known problems.

I have downloaded ubuntu-desktop-22.04.2-amd-64 LTS to the download folder as par the instructions. I have downloaded BalanceEcher-Setup-1.18.8 (ubuntu-22.04.2 image file was formed at the same time).

I rebooted. I received the message "remove media file and press any key" so I did and Windows loaded as normal.

I repeated the process by downloading BalenaEcher-Portable-1.7.9 to the USB. Same result.

Any ideas/help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0):

try to make Ubuntu iso to USB drive by [rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) or [yumi](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) or [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)