# Minimal BASH like line editing is supported Grub error

Tags: boot, windows, reinstall

this might sound ridiculous but it's true and I need your help

I bought an Ubuntu laptop and switched to Windows. Now I want to switch it back to Ubuntu. I'm thinking two options:

1/ Go to Windows Settings, recovery or do something similar to "reset to factory settings) and hopefully it turns back to Ubuntu.
2/ Download an Ubuntu disc image file and reinstall from there.

I tried the second idea but I got this message

> Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
> lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible
> device or file completions.

I also tried the "ls -> set root -> set prefix -> normal" solution but that didn't work.

What else should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)