# PC Continuously reboot after Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, 16.04, 18.04, 22.04, debian

I have a problem with ubuntu starting after installation.

I try to install ubuntu os on my Lenovo L480 laptop and installation is successful, but after how the system asks me to take off the installation usb and reboot the system, the pc starts to continuously reboot without any error message.

PC shows the lenovo logo, and after second step, goes to full reboot.

I tried to install several versions of Ubuntu and the result the same. Each version of ubuntu has the same behaviour.

The Ubuntu ISO was donloaded from Ubuntu Oficial web site and was burned with BalenaEacher software.

The mind linux has the same behaviour.

Then i tried to install other distributive such as Debian, and it works normally and after installation the pc started the os successfully.

What i do wrong. May be i have to do some additional settings on my PC...

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu installed, now? We can really only help, if you have it installed. This can show boot configuration issues: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Some Lenovos have locked RAM issues, but if you were able to install other distributions, then that should not be an issue..

Comment: Your tags are confusing; it's a Debian-Ubuntu workflow issue you've tagged - how does that relate?  What release? as you've tagged multiple systems, where releases of 20.10 & later differ in ISO format to prior releases (*which won't matter if cloned to media, but will impact some formatted-writes*). Please be specific with details, as release particularly matters with some bits like installing (Ubuntu has 5 installers available selected by ISO, we don't even know what release you're using, thus what option(s) you had available)

Comment: Finally I found the ..... not a problem and not an issue..... the doupt was in method of installation of Ubuntu. I tried to install OS in UEFI but it requires LEGACY. All the times I burned my USB iso in UEFI.. and after normal installation it tried to boot it in LEGACY, but no Chance.... After how I installed in Legacy mode, it started normally.... Any way, thank you all for your help!)

Comment: If you write your ISO correctly (*no reformat thus the UEFI/LEGACY option isn't offered; to offer than you're reformatting ISO on write*), the system will install on uEFI with secure-boot *disabled* or *enabled* PLUS it will also install on legacy/CSM hardware without change.  Your last comment implies you didn't write ISO as per documented methods, but reformatted it during write so it would only install on the hardware that matched your selected options. I'm not familiar with *balenaetcher* in writing ISOs so couldn't advise there.

Comment: which app are you familiar with? which app can you advice me for the future?

Comment: There are many people using this site, and we'll all use different tools. Being specific is always helpful; where your tags are *confusing* and ISOs differ in minor ways over releases; thus software like *balenaetcher* needs to be specific versions to write any ISO newer than 20.04 which applies for 22.04 but not 18.04 or 16.04 in your tags. If you write the ISO simply as a *clone* (no reformat so it'll overwrite the whole media) it'll work for all versions (the partition scheme is that used in the ISO itself). Ubuntu has 4 current installers selected at ISO download time & varying on release.

Comment: You mentioned Debian; Debian offers two types of ISOs themselves using different installers; `calamares` for the *live* Debian ISO & *debian installer* for the main ISOs. Ubuntu offers `ubiquity`, `subiquity`, `ubuntu-desktop-installer` & some *flavors* also use `calamares` but you didn't specify ISO; with Ubuntu also offering *debian installer* for 16.04 & 18.04 in your tags, but not later.  Being specific allows us to be more specific.

Comment: [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441/) It's a little late for it now that you've solved your problem by installing Ubuntu in Legacy mode, but the accepted answer to this question maybe would have worked in UEFI mode to begin with.