# Is there any difference between ubuntu server and ubuntu live server?

Tags: server

Is there any difference between ubuntu server and ubuntu live server?
I've downloaded ubuntu server from https://ubuntu.com/download/server and I realized the file named "ubuntu-23.10-**live**-server-amd64.iso". I'm a bit new to ubuntu server so I'm not sure if **live server** is the right version.

Answer (score 2):

The ubuntu-23.10-live-server-amd64.iso file that you downloaded is an ISO image for making a bootable Ubuntu Server 23.10 USB for installing Ubuntu Server 23.10. Instructions for making bootable Ubuntu USB installation media are provided at [What is the proper way of creating installation media from an Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441/).

You can also test Ubuntu Server 23.10 by running a live session from the bootable Ubuntu Server 23.10 USB without installing it on your computer. Any changes you make to the Ubuntu Server while running a live session will not be saved and will be lost after a reboot.